# Каким алгоритмом или формулой можно выяснить, находится ли точка между паралельными прямыми?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Есть две паралельные прямые, заданные уравнениями:

a<sub>1</sub>x + b<sub>1</sub>y + c<sub>1</sub> = 0,
 a<sub>2</sub>x + b<sub>2</sub>y + c<sub>2</sub> = 0.

Как определить, находится ли точка P(x, y) между ними?

Comment: Если не параллельны, у нее нет выбора )))

Comment: Что в вашем понимании значит "меджу ними"? Лучше нарисуйте

Comment: Я так понимаю, надо узнать лежит ли точки внутри угла, образованного пересечением этих прямых?

Comment: @tutankhamun Да, придется для паралельных пока вычислять положение точки... для непаралельных фигня выходит...

Comment: первое что приходит в голову:
дано - прямые A и B и точка P. тогда P лежит между A || B если r(P,A) + r(P,B) < r(A,B)

Comment: Это учебное задание или есть какая-то реальная цель?

Comment: В теории, вроде бы, если подставить координаты точки в уравнения, то если у одного итог будет больше нуля, а у другого меньше нуля - значит между ними.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Так и есть, пишите ответ.

Comment: @tutankhamun это будет часть САПР для окон)))

Answer (score 4):

Например, можно сделать вот как:

Пусть `n` — общий вектор нормали ваших прямых, `A1` и `A2` — точки на 1-ой и 2-ой прямых соответственно, `X` — проверяемая точка. Вычислите скалярные произведения `(XA1, n)` и `(XA2, n)`. Точка лежит внутри, если эти произведения имеют противоположный знак.

---

Для случая не обязательно параллельных прямых и *тупого* угла, у нас появляется *два* вектора нормали `n1` и `n2`. Тогда нужно установить следующие величины: `isFirstDirectionPositive` — знак скалярного произведение `(XA1, n1)` (соответственно, результата подстановки точки в уравнение первой прямой), `isSecondDirectionPositive` — знак скалярного произведения `(XA2, n2)` (соответственно, результата подстановки точки в уравнение второй прямой), и `isAngleBetweenNormalsAcute` — знак скалярного произведения `(n1, n2)`. Вам нужно, чтобы произведение *всех трёх* знаков было положительным.

Comment: Возникает вопрос, если общего вектора нет, что делать? То есть к примеру они немного не паралельные или вектора противоположные.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob: Если они параллельные, вы находите один нормальный вектор, и он будет тоже нормалью для другой прямой.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob: А если они не параллельны («немного не параллельны» = **не** параллельны), то понятие «лежать между двумя прямыми» лишено смысла, потому что тогда прямые делят плоскость на 4 равноправных части.»

Comment: VladD но у меня Идеально паралельных не будет. Даже при расчете все-равно будет ошибка в 12-13 знаке после запятой.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob: Если параллельных не бывает, то любая точка будет _между_ прямыми.

Comment: VladD тогда придется менять условия задачи. Немного не паралельны это Тупой угол. Если точка находится в тупом угле, то считаем что находится между линиями

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob: Дописал ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. уравнение прямой на плоскости, проходящей через точку имеет вид `Ax + Bу + С = 0`, то если `Ax + Bу + С` больше нуля - точка находится выше прямой, если `Ax + Bу + С` меньше нуля - ниже.

Исходя из этого, по логике, надо подставить координаты заданной точки в оба уравнения, и, если результат одного уравнения будет больше нуля, а у другого меньше - значит точка находится между прямыми. Конечно с учетом того, что прямые параллельны

Comment: А что будет, если прямые разнонаправленные? То есть направляющие вектора смотрят в разные стороны.

Comment: у прямой, заданной приведённым в вопросе уравнением, направления нет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Неверно. Замените в уравнении прямой *(A,B,C)* на *(-A,-B,-C)*. Новое уравнение будет определять ту же прямую, но при подстановке `x` в левую часть знак изменится.

Comment: @kff: Но и знак второго выражения тоже изменится, так что знак произведения останется тем же.

Comment: @VladD Не изменится. В условии задачи направляющие вектора прямых не равны: *(A1,B1) != (A2,B2)*. Они лишь коллинеарны.

Comment: @kff: Ответ исходит из равенства. Ну и это самое равенство несложно обеспечить, если прямые реально параллельны.

Comment: @VladD Да, если будет равенство, то верно.

Answer (score 1):

> a<sub>1</sub>x + b<sub>1</sub>y + c<sub>1</sub> = 0 **&&** a<sub>2</sub>x + b<sub>2</sub>y + c<sub>2</sub> = 0

Они параллельны только если коэффициенты кратны. Т. е. надо привести прямые к одинаковым коэффициентам

> ax + by + d<sub>1</sub> = 0 **&&** ax + by + d<sub>2</sub> = 0

В таком виде вопрос сводится к одномерному после подстановки x.

Comment: Не надо делать постановку x. Лучше сделать подстановку `z = ax + by` :)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Подсказали еще один ответ:

```
var sign1 = ((a1 * x + b1 * y + c1) * (a2 * x + b2 * y + c2)) < 0;
var sign2 = (a1 * a2 + b1 * b2) < 0;
return this.xor(sign1, sign2);
```

здесь xor операция исключающая ИЛИ

Comment: Это неверно. Знак `(a1 * a2 + b1 * b2)` не должен играть никакой роли.

Comment: @VladD, странно, но пока это формула работает без ошибок...

Comment: Я понял в чем проблема... Здесь решение задачи, если под определением "Находится между прямыми" считается что точка находится в тупом угле. В общем задачу надо переформулировать. Правда я не знаю как сделать, так как тут уже дали ответы под текущие условия.

Comment: Угу. Дополнение к моему ответу по сути даёт ту же формулу.

Answer (score 0):

Предствами уравнения в форме угловых коэффициентов и смещений:

> y = k<sub>1</sub>x + b<sub>1</sub>,  где: k<sub>1</sub> = -A<sub>1</sub>\B<sub>1</sub>,  b<sub>1</sub> = -C<sub>1</sub>\B<sub>1</sub>
>
> y = k<sub>2</sub>x + b<sub>2</sub>,  где: k<sub>2</sub> = -A<sub>2</sub>\B<sub>2</sub>,  b<sub>2</sub> = -C<sub>2</sub>\B<sub>2</sub>

Тогда, так как прямые параллельны то k<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>2</sub> = k. Теперь попробуем провести через P другую прямую также параллельную исходным, ее уравнение будет иметь вид:

> y<sub>P</sub> = kx<sub>P</sub> + b<sub>P</sub>, от куда b<sub>P</sub> = y<sub>P</sub> - kx<sub>P</sub>

Прямая с токой P будет лежать между двумя исходными, если смещение b<sub>P</sub> будет находится между смещениями b<sub>1</sub> и b<sub>2</sub>:

> b<sub>1</sub> ≤ b<sub>2</sub> → b<sub>1</sub> ≥ b<sub>P</sub> ∧ b<sub>P</sub> ≤ b<sub>2</sub>
>
> b<sub>1</sub> ≥ b<sub>2</sub> → b<sub>2</sub> ≥ b<sub>P</sub> ∧ b<sub>P</sub> ≤ b<sub>1</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Если прямые пересекаются, то точка - либо на одной из прямых, либо между ними.
Если параллельны, то сверяются знаки при подстановке точки в уравнения.

```
eps = 1e-7;
comp = eps*(a1*a1 + b1*b1)*(a2*a2+b2*b2);
det = a1*b2 - a2*b1;
val = (a1*b1+a2*b2)(a1*x+b1*y+c1)(a2*x+b2*y+c2);
if (det*det < comp) return (val < comp) ? 0: 1;   
return (a1*b1+a2*b2)(a1*x+b1*y+c1)(a2*x+b2*y+c2) < 0 ? 1 :0;
```